Zooming HTML background-image on hover with CSS
I have this code:
<div class="ver-thin">
  <div class="img-div" style="background-image: url('https://preludica.com/img/featured.webp');"></div>
  <span>
    <h4>Item title</h4>
    <p class="text">Item description.</p>
  </span>
</div>

.ver-thin {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: var(--thin-gap); /*about 50px*/
}

.img-div {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

I just wish this background-image to zoomin on hover, while inside its parent ver-thin with CSS.
Could you help me?
Already tried background-size but without succcess. I do not know much about advanced CSS, so every help helps! :)

Could you show us the code you have tried.

BTW you may like to put your code through a validator, it is invalid (eg h4 element in a span)

Pls show us your css code. Should be working using background-size, you will be zooming but within the size of the ver-thin div.

Do you want the zooming to be gradual or just a jump to the new size? I ask because background-size is not animatable. Try scale instead.

yes! I tried transform: scale(1.2) instead of background-size, but the image zoomed beyond the ver-thin div :(

Well here is a minimal reproduction from your code. As there is no css provided, so I just assumed it and this is for demo purpose only.
The requirement is achievable by background-size. Although, triggering it on hover might get tricky. The more better way to have a background image would be having it into the ver-thin css class, instead of rendering a separate div just to contain the background image. But as there is no other code, so I assume it would be necessary for your use-case. Anyway, here is the break down of what I did:

I applied a position relative to the parent div i.e ver-then. This is because, we would like to have a background image rendered inside a child div.
I applied position absolute to img-div so that it could be positioned freely relative to its parent div. I set its initial background-size to be 100% but you may change it according to your requirement.
I then wrote a css selector to change the styles of img-div, whenever user hovers over the ver-then div. And inside that selector, I increased the background-size of the img-div to be 150%.
You can change the size according to your requirements and refactor the code.
One thing though, currently background or background-size changes cannot be transitioned using normal transition rule. To make a smooth effect you would need to write your own key-frame animation, which you can find on code pen. So in my code the line transition: all backgorund-size 0.8s ease; does not have any effect on background size changes.



.ver-thin{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.img-div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all backgorund-size 0.8s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}
.ver-thin:hover .img-div{
  background-size: 150%;
}
<div class="ver-thin">
  <div class="img-div" style="background-image: url('https://preludica.com/img/featured.webp');"></div>
  <span>
    <h4>Item title</h4>
    <p class="text">Item description.</p>
  </span>
</div>



